# SQL queries causing deadlock errors

Tags: sql, deadlock

There is an update query which causes deadlock errors I don't know why. There is already (rowlock, updlock) hint used in the update query still it gives deadlock error.

Sample query:

```
update table a with (rowlock, updlock) 
set a.column1 = value
```

This same query is used in several stored procedures which may be called simultaneously. But since a lock is specified should it still causes a deadlock

Comment: I suppose you know that deadlock cannot occur because of 1 query? you need at least 2 and uncommitted transaction

Comment: You'll have to provide more context to get help.  Perhaps add a few snippets of your code.

Comment: I have updated the post. This same query is used in several places which may be resulting in deadlock. so assist on this.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: This is for SQL SERVER

Comment: if the same query without a `WHERE` is executed from multiple procedures at the same time, then it might be better to use a `TABLOCK` to maintain sequence between the updates. Also if the table has large number of rows, row level locks and its book keeping will consume more memory.

Answer (score 0):

[Deadlock](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177433(v=sql.105).aspx) occurs when two or more tasks permanently block each other by each task having a lock on a resource which the other tasks are trying to lock.

Since your are explicitly specifying `with (rowlock, updlock)` which add a lock upon transaction. Eventually, when one transaction is being executed, it places a lock on the table. If another transaction wants to access that same record, it will have to wait until the previous transaction finishes and remove the lock for it to proceed.

Using `with NOLOCK` enables you to bypass the locks but in case of update, that would be too risky. More so, as you mentioned, several update can be executed simultaneously.

In your case, it seems that the Locks is the culprit. But however, Locks are not the only source of deadlocks. It might be memory issues or thread execution also. This [LINK](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104(v=sql.105).aspx) might help you identify the real cause of your deadlock.